# Android bluetooth get response with BluetoothGatt

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm new in connection bluetooth. I use code of
https://github.com/Fakher-Hakim/android-BluetoothLeGatt. When I try to
obtain the information nothing happened.

```
public String response() {
    if (mConnected) {
        mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristica);
        byte response[] = characteristica.getValue();
        String respuesta = ReadBytes(response);
        mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
        return respuesta;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I execute after function

```
private final ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener servicesListClickListner
```

How I can obtain information of the Bluetoothdevice?

Answer (score 0):

The BLE operations are asynchronous, you have to deal with the result in the callback.
In your example: https://github.com/Fakher-Hakim/android-BluetoothLeGatt/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothlegatt/BluetoothLeService.java

Check the onCharacteristicRead method.